# VLC Aspect Ratio Snapping Explanation

Tags: c#, activex, vlc, aspect-ratio, libvlc

I am programming a measuring tool which makes use of the AxVLC library. I have successfully created the tool, but when someone loaded a *720x480* video, some measurements were off.

After some digging in the VideoLAN forums and my code, I learned that VLC snaps the video to a 16:9 aspect ratio when it displays, but the height and width listed in AxVLCPlugin.video is still *720x480*, which would be a "3:2" aspect ratio.

I can program my measurements to account for this, but

---

I need to know whether VLC always snaps to 16:9 if it encounters an unknown aspect ratio or if it snaps according to some algorithm or lookup table, because i would like to fix this for all video dimensions rather than just *720x480*.

---

No information is available to suggest the current aspect ratio of the displayed video in the ActiveX control as the AxVLCPlugin.video.aspectRatio field is always blank, unless the value existed in the video's metadata and setting it in code does nothing to the actual displayed video.

the set of all available aspect ratios in VLC is as follows:

- (null)
- Default
- 16:9
- 4:3
- 1:1
- 16:10
- 2.21:1
- 2.35:1
- 2.39:1
- 5:4

according to this https://www.vlchelp.com/fix-stretched-video-in-vlc-by-changing-aspect-ratio
as well as according to opening VLC media player myself and just looking at the list.

so far i have not found a way to force source aspect ratio as you can from a vlc command line execution(as listed in the official VLC docs) but if i could force it to display the video at its original aspect ratio, that would work just as well.

3:2 gets snapped to 16:9, which skips right over 16:10 between them, so i know it is not simply snapping to the next highest or lowest aspect ratio, but for the sake of good code, I would like to know what it actually snaps to.
If it just snaps to 16:9 by default, i can work with that,
if it snaps in some strange order or according to some odd range table, i can work with that,
if you know how to force the original aspect ratio in the activeX control through C#, i can work with that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jody - I don't know how to answer your question but I was wondering if you know of a way to fit the video to the axVLCPlayer control window?

Comment: You cannot. The axVLCPlayer control is a canvas that hooks up to a video buffer. That video buffer will exclusively produce the video in a given aspect ratio. It will automatically pad black wherever there is extra space in the canvas it displays that buffer on, always maintaining aspect ratio. The solution was that i had to do all the math to figure out where the padding was and how much there should be at any given time given the current dimensions and the video's dimension and apply that transformation to all measurements.

Comment: Thanks for the info Jody - it certainly works a lot different than the Windows Media Player activex control window: using the WMP activex control I can easily tell the video to fit to the window.

Comment: To be fair. Its been a while since I've used it, but iirc you cannot. You only have the option of a few preset aspect ratios.

Comment: @NealDavis Hi, i don't know if this is still an ongoing issue for you, but i have recently found the open source project MPV. It is **very** robust and will likely provide you with better functionality than axVLC, also crossplatform.
[link](https://mpv.io/)

Comment: Thanks Jody looking into MPV!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm curious about what you ended up doing.  I'm at the point of tracing through the VLC source code.

Comment: Hey Scott. I abandoned vlc because it presented many more issues than that in various way, from buffering issues to time tracking issues. As far as i was aware at the time, VLC's development had basically come to a stand still other than maintenance. so i unless i was wrong all along or they've redone a bunch of code(this is total conjecture) I recommend that you look into MPV or any other open source solution. MPV is versatile and i bet it can handle what you'd like to throw at it. Give it a try and see if you can have it embedding video in a standalone application within a day. Resizing too.